# Any hope of recovering a missing vim .swp file?

Tags: data-recovery

So I'm plugging along on a file with vim and I save it with `:w` and the terminal freezes up and I reboot. Two of the vim files I had opened show zero bytes. "No problem," I think. I recover one of them with `:recover` command. However, the second file doesn't have a `.swp` file! I have no idea what happened. Is there any possible way I can recover this file?

Note: I'm on a Debian machine.

Comment: In my opinion, I would force poweroff to avoid overwriting any more data.  I would then boot up on a USB stick with linux and install ext4magic or extundelete or both and see if they can find your files, assuming your device is ext3 or 4.

Comment: This was on a guest virtualbox machine. The host crashed.

Comment: OK, looks like my /dev/sda1 is an ext4 fs. I'll try those tools. Thanks.

Comment: Did the second file have a name (i.e., did you just do `vi` without a name)?  If so, you might have a file named simply `.swp`.  If so, you can do: `vi -r .swp` to recover the content.  If you have `.swp`, you recover it, and it's the content you were looking for, also look for `.swn`, `.swo`, ...